# SMTP config for gmail?

Tags: java, email, ssl, smtp, gmail

I am trying to configure an Email notification in TeamCity server.

I read [this](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Setting+up+Google+Mail+and+Google+Talk+as+Notification+Servers) and [this](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7104828?visit_id=1-636122998231733350-823687448&rd=3) documentation, and tried to set the configs

Here are 2 configs which I tried and the respective errors I receive when I press the `Test connection` button below it:

### Config 1

```
SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com
SMTP port: 465
Send email messages from: foobar@gmail.com
SMTP login: foobar@gmail.com
SMTP password: •••••••••
Secure connection: SSL
```

#### Error:

> javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host:
>   smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;   nested exception is:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

### Config 2

```
SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com
SMTP port: 587
Send email messages from: foobar@gmail.com
SMTP login: foobar@gmail.com
SMTP password: •••••••••
Secure connection: StartTSL
```

#### Error:

> javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
>   nested exception is: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

What is going wrong over here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I run into the same problem, in my case disabling AVAST was enough to solve the issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27389691/1259763

Hope it helps!

Comment: solution worked :) ... But I wanted understand why antivirus is blocking it? any workaround to perform action without disabling antivirus, because in real world organizations won't do that.

Comment: Disabling the antivirus worked for me as well. I just would like to know how to avoid the error without disabling the antivirus, in case the antivirus must be enabled.

Comment: Adding an exception to the antivirus does not help

Answer (score 4):

I disabled the antivirus and it worked :)