# Getting error on Test configuration by sending test e-mail for Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am getting error on Jenkins Email test.I have created the app password for gmail and used in jenkin SMTP Authentication in Test configuration by sending test e-mail .But still getting error as

```
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error is complaining about the missing public certificate of the Gmail server. You can try importing the Gmail SMTP servers' public cert to the Jenkins Keystore or you can try disabling SSL in the Mail configurations.

---

**Update**

Since you are connecting to Gmail, typically the certificates will be available in your JDK installation. So there could be an issue with the JDK installation. Check the answers in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098281/my-java-program-stopped-sending-emails-using-my-gmail-account).

Comment: How to import Gmail SMTP public cert.I do not have any GCP account credentials.When we disable SSL we get SocketTimeoutException

Comment: @AshishJain check the updated answer.

Comment: I followed above question link.But still not resolved.I have jdk 17 downloaded from  Oracle website.I just want to see the test results of pass fail test cases through email